# Nothing happens when listening on a TCP port

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to write a small, example app to listen to a TCP port, but it's not working for some reason.

It see seems to reach `accept(3p)`, but `lsof -i :1080` reports that nothing is listening on that port. There are not errors, or anything else remotely obvious.

Any hints?

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>

const int THREADS = 4;
const int BUFFER_SIZE = 256;

void usage(char *app_name) {
    printf("Usage: %s PORT\n", app_name);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    struct sockaddr_in6 serv_addr, addr_cli;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int sockfd, sock_cli, n, port;

    if (argc < 2) {
        usage(argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }

    port = atoi(argv[1]);

    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
        perror("Could not open socket");
        return errno;
    }

    serv_addr.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
    serv_addr.sin6_port = htonl(port);
    // other addresses: INADDR_LOOPBACK, INADDR_ANY
    serv_addr.sin6_addr = in6addr_any;
    serv_addr.sin6_scope_id = 0;

    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) != 0) {
        perror("Could not bind to socket");
        return errno;
    }

    if (listen(sockfd, THREADS + 1) < 0) {
        perror("Could not listen to socket");
        return errno;
    }

    printf("Listening on :%d\n", port);

    unsigned long l;
    if ((sock_cli = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &addr_cli, (socklen_t*) &l)) != 0) {
        perror("Could not accept connections on socket");
        return errno;
    }

    printf("Connection accepted\n");

    while ((n = recv(sock_cli, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0)) > 0) {
        printf("> Got data: %s\n", buffer);
    }

    if (n < 0) {
        printf("Could not receive data\n");
        return errno;
    }

    printf("Bye!\n");
}
```

Comment: htonl(port) should be htons(port)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got your program to work

```
$ ./hugo 8888 &
[1] 25330
$ Listening on :8888
telnet -6 localhost 8888
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection accepted
hello 
> Got data: hello
^]
telnet> quit
Connection closed.
Bye!
[1]+  Exit 10                 ./hugo 8888
```

making the following changes:

```
#include <netinet/in.h>
...
serv_addr.sin6_port = htons(port);
...
if ((sock_cli = accept(sockfd,  
                       (struct sockaddr *) &addr_cli, 
                       (socklen_t*) &l)) == -1) {
```

As the comment suggested, **htons**(3) causes the correct port to be listened to.  And **accept**(2) returns a socket, so you have test explicitly for `-1`.

If I could suggest two small things,

- return EXIT_SUCCESS from `main`.  :-)
- use **err**(3) instead of **perror**(3).  Less typing, and you really don't want to return `errno` anyway.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! The `htons` vs `htonl` made the difference. Thanks for the extra suggestions too!

Comment: Why are you including `netinet/in.h`? I'm not getting a `Could not accept connections on socket: Invalid argument`; did I miss something? There's nothing _obvious_ broken I can see.